# Are any of the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have the next picture and I need to know what are homeomorphic

[image]

Comment: What do you think yourself?

Comment: You can do this by thinking about what open neighborhoods of various points look like. Most of the points have open neighborhoods that look like small intervals so they're unhelpful. But some of the points have different neighborhoods and you can use those.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: All of those sets are connected. A point of a connected set is a *cut point* if removing it disconnects the set. If a connected space $X$ has a cut point whose removal disconnects $X$ into $n$ components, any space homeomorphic to $X$ must also have such a point. You can use this fact to settle the question completely for your four spaces.